# How to select entry with greater value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two or more values like:

```
c1|c2 |c3 |c4 
--+---+---+---
1 | Z | B | 29
2 | Z | B | 19
```

and I want to have the entry with the larger c4 value:

```
1 | Z | B | 29
```

I tried to query the max value from c4, after a group by of c2 and c3, but this doesn't work.

Comment: This gets asked a lot. Just search for `postgresql` and the term `greatest-n-per-group`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group to get many more answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres specific solution:

```
select distinct on (c2,c3) c1, c2, c3, c4
from the_table
order by c2,c3,c4 desc
```

ANSI SQL solution:

```
select c1,c2,c3,c4
from (
  select c1,c2,c3,c4,
         row_number() over (partition by c2,c3 order by c4 desc) as rn
  from the_table
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order results in descending order by `c4` and output only one row ([see LIMIT clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-limit.html)):

```
SELECT *
 FROM table_name
 ORDER BY c4 DESC
 LIMIT 1
```